# How to authenticate azure devops pipeline , so that pipeline can restore yarn packages successfully

Tags: azure-devops, yarnpkg, build-pipeline, npm-registry, .npmrc

My application uses an yarn package which is installed in local after authentication.Registry url is specified in .npmrc file. Now my build pipeline fails, and says "Package restore failed" (Request failed "401 Unauthorized""). How to authenticate the azure devops build pipeline?

I tried adding a task in my YML file as below , specified the npmrc path in it,so that it silently authenticate from the pipeline process, but this doesn't work

```
task: npmAuthenticate@0
    inputs:
      workingFile: "Portal/.npmrc"
      customEndpoint: msasg.pkgs.visualstudio.com, 1DS-SDK
      displayName: "Authenticate NPM"
```

Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you use [Yarn task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UofN7.png) in the pipeline? Can you share your build definition?

Comment: This could be a misalignment between `.npmrc` and the registry entries in `yarn.lock`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Yarn](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn) Task from the Marketplace as it is more Azure DevOps aware and can handle this credentials bit for you.

[image]

In addition, the yarn package you use is installed locally, do you use a self-hosted agent to run the pipeline ?